# Nodatime How do I serialize ZonedDateTime to ISO-8601 format using System.Text.Json

Tags: json, asp.net-core, iso8601, nodatime, zoneddatetime

Is there a way to serialize a ZonedDateTime to an ISO 8601 string using System.Text.Json?

I'm currently getting output in this format 2020-03-15T15:14:53Z UTC which isn't ISO 8061 compliant.

The end goal is to feed this into Moment.js for further formatting

EDIT: Adding code snippet, noting complex, just creating a ZonedDateTime from a DateTimeOffset

```
//Incoming Date format "Mon Feb 10 16:46:03 +0000 2020"
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat);
var zdt = dto.ToZonedDateTime();
```

Comment: Did you try this:`DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u").Replace(' ', 'T');`?Could you share a sample code and give the result of your scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO-8601 doesn't have any representation of time zones - only UTC offsets. (It's unfortunate that it refers to those as time zones, but they're not.)

If you're constructing `ZonedDateTime` from a `DateTimeOffset`, I'd suggest not doing that, and instead using `OffsetDateTime`, which actually represents the information you have. (You could parse that directly from the initial value too, rather than going via `DateTimeOffset`.)

While I haven't checked, I'd expect the `OffsetDateTime` JSON representation to be an ISO-8601 format.

Comment: Thanks, you mention parsing without going via DateTimeOffset, I can only see doing that via LocaDateTime and an Offset which seems more complex? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidHayes: Perhaps you're missing `OffsetDateTimePattern`, which is the natural way of parsing an `OffsetDateTime`?